# How can I introduce an artificial delay based on the HTTP Response

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have an API that can return a response of 'RequestedTooSoon' and includes a 'NotBefore' timestamp.

My goal is to introduce an artificial delay so that it appears to any consumers that the request simply took longer than it did. The response should be delayed until the 'NotBefore' time has passed.

```
// Consumer:
verifyAuth() {
  authService.verify(...).subscribe(...)
}
```

Inside my `AuthService.verify(...)` method I am attempting to *throttle* the response, however reading the `RxJS` docs a little closer it has become apparent `throttle` is not the operator I am looking for:

```
this.apiHttp.post<VerificationResponse>('api/verify', ...)
  .pipe(
    throttle(response => {
      const nowInMs = Date.now();
      const throttle = response.NotBefore.getTime() - nowInMs;

      return timer(throttle);
    })
  )
```

I haven't been able to identify the appropriate operator (if one exists).

Is there an out-of-the-box operator that can achieve what I am after? Or is there a more appropriate approach?

My next step will be to implement a `delay` operator that accepts a `durationSelector`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is already a delay, seeing it take a fixed value you will need to switchMap to it so you can run a function to determine the time to input

```
this.apiHttp.post<VerificationResponse>('api/verify', ...)
  .pipe(
    switchMap(response => of(response).pipe(
      delay(response.NotBefore.getTime() - (new Date()).getTime()))
    )
  )
```

Comment: It looks like this approach will give me what I need. My only criticism (and it's possibly a criticism of RxJS itself) is that it feels a little like an abuse of `switchMap`. I'm not really 'switching to a new observable'. I guess I can think of it as switching from _the response_ to _the response with a delay_.

Comment: You need to switchMap because you don't know the delay at the time of creating the observable, you need to calculate the delay time with data from the response. If you wanted to delay with a value that can be calculated before the response is received then you don't need switchMap.